# Is Arrays.sort() fast?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have compared Arrays.sort() to [QuickX](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/QuickX.java.html) and [MergeX](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/MergeX.java.html) written by [Robert Sedgewick](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs) and [Kevin Wayne](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne) with [random](https://github.com/leorge/QuickJava/blob/master/random.awk) data.

```
$ ./compare MergeX ArraysSort QuickX QuickLog2
N = 2000000
MergeX sec. = 1.835
Arrays sec. = 1.946
QuickX sec. = 1.698
QuickLog2 sec. = 1.574

N = 4000000
MergeX sec. = 4.091
Arrays sec. = 4.082
QuickX sec. = 3.826
QuickLog2 sec. = 3.474

N = 8000000
MergeX sec. = 9.007
Arrays sec. = 8.602
QuickX sec. = 8.183
QuickLog2 sec. = 7.445
```

[compare](https://github.com/leorge/QuickJava/blob/master/compare) is a shell script.
ArraysSort calls java.util.arrays.sort().

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = StdIn.readAllStrings();
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    java.util.Arrays.sort(a);
    double elapsedTime = timer.elapsedTime();
    show(a);
    if (isSorted(a)) StdOut.println("Arrays sec. = " + elapsedTime);
}
```

QuickX and MergeX is modified to output elapsed time like ArraysSort.
[QuickLog2](https://github.com/leorge/QuickJava/wiki/Median-of-Log2(N)) is [my quicksort](https://github.com/leorge/QuickJava).

ArraysSort is slower **5%** than **QuickX**.
Is there something wrong in my inspection?
Is there some magic in Java?
I'm new to Java.
Why is not quicksort used for object array?

I found a [tuned quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776011/what-is-the-difference-between-quicksort-and-tuned-quicksort) in this site on the way I'm writing this question.
Is it slower than timsort?

My environment is...

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Java benchmarking is significantly more difficult than this, because e.g. the JIT optimizes code that gets run a lot.  You really need to use something like JMH or Caliper before you can make any claims about one piece of code being faster than another.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman : Thanks for you advice. I'll search JMH or Caliper now.

Comment: Also, Arrays.sort has to be a stable sort, meaning a mergesort variation in practice.  Its possible an unstable sort like quicksort could beat it in some cases, but Arrays.sort is intended to be competitive with other sorts while being usable in all situations.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman : Thanks again. Stable quicksort is slower than unstable.